# Why my problem ID is gone after inserting <apex:detail/>

Tags: visualforce

I used the below code to demonstrate a case ID:

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" extensions="ProblemGenerater">
  <apex:detail />
  <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Problem">
       <apex:commandButton action="{!CreateProblem}" value="New Problem" />
       <p></p>
       Problem ID: {!Problem}
    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

And I am using the website url looks like: /apex/xxx?id=....&problemID=...

In the controller, the code related to this question part is:

```
{
    this.current = (Case)controller.getRecord();
    if (String.isNotBlank(Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('ProblemId')))
    {
        problem = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('ProblemId');
    }    
}
```

It works fine when I remove the  line. But when I added that line, the problem ID just doesn't show at the place. Why is that? And how can I resolve this?

Comment: Can you please update your question and paste the code from your extension class?

Comment: Make sure you're problem variable has getter and setter `{get; set;}`

Answer (score 2):

In your current example by `{!problem}` you're referencing to a variable in your controller or extension class. So if you want to go along that path, make sure you have a variable declared in the class with access modifier of public and have a getter and setter.

```
public String problem {get; set;}

// then in your constructor
problem = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('problemID');
```

Alternatively, you can reference it straight from the visualforce page by using the global variable:

`Problem ID: {!$CurrentPage.parameters.problemID}`

Comment: I guess it is just some odd feature of Salesforce. I closed the whole browser and opened again and the problem got solved automatically.